# Где ошибка в коде?Java

Tags: java

Вот код, задание было найти сумму арифметической прогрессии , но при проверке числа 123456, получается неправильный ответ :(

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        int N = scanner.nextInt();
        int S = ((N+1)*N)/2;
         System.out.println(S);
    }
}
```

Comment: думаете,  знание количества элементов достаточно, чтобы посчитать сумму?

Comment: "получается неправильный ответ" - какой?

Comment: @tym32167 известно что первый элемент прогрессии 1 , из этого все и упрощается

Comment: @Igor получается  -969180896 , а должно быть 7620753696

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
123456 * 123457 = 15 241 507 392
```

Сколько там у нас максимум помещается в `int`? Четыре миллиарда?

---

```
long S = N;
S = S * (S + 1) / 2;
```